# ASP.NET Dynamic Control Addition

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, repeater

**ORIGINAL POST**

There are a **ton** of articles out there and a lot more questions than answers posted here on SO for my particular question.

I have a web page that I'm creating that will have a DropDownList control of *products* a user can select from to enter into an *order* for processing. In addition to that there are two (2) other DropDownList controls that contain *options* and *accessories* for each particular *product*. I want the user to be able to enter in multiple *product* lines into the *order* object for processing along with corresponding *options* and/or *accessories. This will reduce the amount of records to store for customer information within the database.

As the user is selecting from this DropDownList I would like to create a list of *products* but this list will have to be created dynamically based upon the number of *products* the user has to enter for a specific *order*. I understand the needs involved of saving the data as it is not automatically saved to the ViewState but having trouble figuring out how to push the data in the right direction.

Should I be looking to use something other than ASP.NET to create my web page due to the complexities of dealing with the ViewState? While it may be complex, is there a better methodology to use when attempting such a course of action?

**EDIT**

So my findings are bringing me to believe that in order to store the data properly as it is being added I should be using a Repeater control and DataBind that to a Dictionary object containing my data in KeyValuePairs. I'm looking for a simplified way of doing this to instead just add directly an object that contains all data I would need. I can certainly add this class to the Repeater and DataBind to it but re-hydrating the data back out of the Repeater is causing me more than a few issues.

```
public class Order
{
    public Order() { }
    public string CustomerNamer { get; set; }
    public ProductList ProductOrdered { get; set; }
}
public class ProductList : List<Product>
{
     public ProductList() { }
}
public class Product
{
     public Product() { }
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string ProdcutCode { get; set; }
}
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void order_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Dictionary<int, Order> objOrders = new Dictionary<int, Order>();

        Order objOrder = new Order();
        Product objProduct = new Product();

        objProduct.Name = "Tire";
        objProduct.ProductCode = "75R15";

        objOrder.ProductsOrdered = new ProductList();

        objOrder.ProductsOrdered.Add(objProduct);

        objOrders.Add(0, objOrder);

        rptTest.DataSource = objOrders;
        rptTest.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with using .NET or see any complexities with ViewState. What is the "right direction" in which you are trying to push the data? Database, Session...?

Comment: For the moment I need the information stored in the ViewState so that on PostBack of some type of submit or save button I can take the controls and read out the data for compilation into a data object class for posting to a MySql DAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic collections which are represented via a `Repeater` in the rendered page I've successfully used this pattern many times:

Create an in-memory structure that    can represent the information.

Expose    this structure as a property on the    page, and internally store it in the    `Session` or `ViewState` as    appropriate.

`public List<Order> Orders 
{
   get { return ViewState("OrdersList"); }
   set { ViewState("OrdersList") = value; }
}`

`DataBind()` to the    repeater and have the binding    transform your in-memory object to    whatever it should look like when    rendered.

On post-back, read any    changes from the repeater and update    your in-memory data structure (in    `Page_Load` handler -> `if    (!IsPostback) {...}`).

When it's time to persist selection to DB (or submit the order, etc.) simply read info from your in-memory store.

Comment: Putting a full list of objects in the ViewState can have some performance impact as the size of the HTML page sent back to the client may be huge.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: If you're not storing the objects in ViewState as the user is functionally creating them with the ASPX page then where do YOU store them? I'm all ears.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: This is true - there is a performance hit as ViewState will grow. Alternative is to use Session which remains on the server or override `Page` to persist ViewState somewhere else (like in Session) by overriding `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium()` and `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium` event handlers. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic10)

Comment: @Jeff - In general, you don't have to store the same data at two different places. If you manage orders, they are probably stored in a backend database, and you don't need to have it on the client HTML page (because they will need to be serialized back & forth at each user request and the database is better for this). That *can* be done, it can technically work, but you have to take care. ViewState exists more for transient information that currently resides nowhere else (like the content of a form not yet saved but that you need to keep at each user request).

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Your last statement points to my question exactly. I have an object of Orders being created in the form and it will dynamically grow depending on the number of Products the user chooses to add to the form. So new controls are added to the form dynamically based upon user into. I don't know that saving an Order object to the database and posting it back each time that a Postback is committed as controls are added is going to be the proper way to handle it. So ViewState here I come!

Comment: Zombie post, but here goes:  I agree very much with Simon.  If you want the user to select items from a dataset, you don't need to store the entire dataset as part of the viewstate. Just store the PK values from your database, as the user selects them with JavaScript. Store these during run-time in a HiddenField element, then read that element using `Request.Form[""]` during postback.  You can then re-query the necessary data. Storing large amounts of data in ViewState is only going to lead to a maintenance nightmare for someone, someday.